# Cannot convert generic type

Tags: swift, syntax

Why do I get this error ?

> Cannot convert type of FetchResultsController < Entity > to expected
>   argument type of FetchedResultsController < NSManagedObject >

```
protocol FetchedResultsControllerDelegate: class {
  func fetchedResultsControllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: FetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>)
}

open class FetchedResultsController<Entity: NSManagedObject>: NSObject {

  weak var delegate: FetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

  func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    delegate?.fetchedResultsControllerWillChangeContent(self) // here
  }

}
```

Comment: If the protocol is given an associated type of T: NSManagedObject then the problem is solved. I suppose this is just a limitation of the syntax. An associated type results in an error with var delegate though

Comment: Can you provide more info on this?